# How to build a pipeline for multiple transformers models?

Tags: pytorch, pipeline, huggingface-transformers, torch, huggingface

I am trying to make a pipeline for a natural language to SQL translation task.

To solve the problem, I need multiple transformers for entity extraction, query generation, and so on.
I looked for the `Pipeline` in HuggingFace, but it seems like it is only for a one transofrmer model. (it only takes one model and one tokenizer).

Is there a proper way to build a pipeline which uses multiple transformers with huggingface interface?

```py
class MultiplePipeline(Pipeline):
    def __init__():
        self.extractor = AutoModel.from_pretrained()
        self.query_generator = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained()
    
    def _forward(self, x):
        x = self.extractor(x)
        x = self.query_generator(x)
        ...
```

or else, what should I do for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a PyTorch model with multiple transformers with HuggingFace library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894008/how-to-create-a-pytorch-model-with-multiple-transformers-with-huggingface-librar)

Comment: @alvas No this is a different question. The question you linked is about using multiple transformers at the same time in one module. This is a question about pipelining (sequential order)

Comment: Quick question, which machine are you using? Can they fit in all the models you need? Also, regardless of using the model all together and/or sequentially, you'll end up the same mechanism to load multiple models , then use them sequentially or in parallel.

Comment: @alvas Thanks for answering. First, I will train the model separately with GPU machines. But I will load them at the same time on CPU at the inference time. Second, I also thought that both methods can end up the same way. That is why I left those questions on stackoverflow to check if there are any pre-defined ways to do things with HuggingFace library.

Comment: Hmmm, which models are you going to load to CPUs "at the same time". I think it's possible but not practical, without changing the models' generate/inference code, either you will get out of memory or the inference latency will be unreasonably long.

Comment: can multi-task training help?